# Express the class of the polynomial $3x^2 + 2x - 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to express the class of the polynomial $3x^2 + 2x - 2$ in the basis of the quotient space of the real-variable polynomials of degree equal or less to 3 by the kernel of a given linear mapping.

I found that the basis of this space is $B = ((1,0,0) + ker f, (0,0,1) + ker f )$.

How do I found the coordinates of the class of the polynomial in this basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you meant $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq2}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq3}$.)

The coordinates of the polynomial $3x^2+2x-2$ in the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq2}$, $\{1,X,X^2\}$ are $(-2,2,3)$.

The basis $B=((1,0,0)+kerf,(0,0,1)+kerf)$ has been obtained by completion of a basis of $kerf$, so I will asume $(0,1,0)$ is such base.

Since the quotient space is a vector space we can express the class of $(-2,2,3)$,$[(-2,2,3)]=[(-2,0,0)]+[(0,2,0)]+[(0,0,3)]=-2[(1,0,0)]+2[(0,1,0)]+3[(0,0,1)]$.
Since (0,1,0) is basis of $kerf$ then $[(0,1,0)]=[0]$.

Therefore $[(-2,2,3)]=(-2,3)$ in basis $B$.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped!